# How do I prevent random people from seeing my last name & profile picture via Google?

Tags: gmail, google-account, privacy

Whenever someone tries to log into Google and enters what also happens to be my go-to username for gaming on various platforms, my profile picture and full name appear (both covered here).
Is there a way to prevent this from happening, aside from changing my Google name and profile picture to a fake one or creating a new Gmail account?

[image: Google Login - Password prompt with name formerly visible, but covered here]

Comment: Use a guest OS account for other people to use your machine or routinely remove the account after you have logged out of your Google account from the list of accounts Google knows (quick login or whatever google calls it)

Comment: @Ramhound my concern isn't with people using my machine (none other than me), but rather with people being able to know my first and last name by attempting to log into my account, i.e. doxxing me.

Comment: Your name is only displayed once you have successfully logged into a previous session.  Without access to your machine nobody can know your name.  What you see is only displayed to you (at least that screenshot).

Comment: Well, I created a Firefox Private Browsing window, went to Gmail, was prompted to sign up or in, typed in my username and that's what I get.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok so this is interesting. When connecting with my home IP address it shows me my name, when I'm not it doesn't, and instead shows me a generic "Welcome" message and empty profile picture. None of that has to do with whether or not I was logged into my Google account or not previously on that account. As if Google "trusted" my IP address.

Comment: How Google determines what you see would have to be answered by Google.  All I know is my many years of using Google accounts is that only someone who has logged into your account before will see that information.  Now if you send them an email, your name might be exposed,  so there is always that.  At the end of the day Google will show that information if Google decides to show that information.  Your only choice is not use Google accounts.

Comment: That's fine by me. I expect people I talk to via Email to know who I am. I just don't want randos to be able to just get my name through my IGN with such a simple trick. From this I gather it's not the case, hence the problem isn't there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You [noticed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139702/how-do-i-prevent-random-people-from-seeing-my-last-name-profile-picture-via-go#comment128107_139702) that:

> *When connecting with my home IP address it shows me my name, when I'm not it doesn't, and instead shows me a generic "Welcome" message and empty profile picture.*

The reason being you had -sometime in the past- logged in your account using a normal window and NOT a private one and your cookies are still there.

That is what Google reads and "trusts" your IP address.

Comment: If by cookies you mean server-side data then sure. But when you open a private window, all cookies get temporarily discarded.

Comment: You can test it by using another "clean" browser and not Firefox (maybe even from a different computer). By clean I mean where all Google and Google related cookies have been deleted or have never been used before to log-in using a normal window.

Comment: I just installed another browser, this time on my Android phone (Firefox Focus) and guess what? The same occurs. If I use mobile data it shows "Welcome", on Wi-Fi it shows my name.

Comment: @Manchineel a new browser on an Android phone will look at the accounts you have saved on your device. Please simply open a private window.

Comment: @ahorn Firefox Focus is like a privacy browser with only private browsing mode, it's is meant for sensitive stuff you don't want to log: it doesn't save any cookies past a restart, doesn't have bookmarking, downloads or even multiple tabs. It cannot access the file system and doesn't even request permission to see accounts on the device. But I've tried everything (private tab on a freshly installed Ubuntu included) and the result is always the same: it only shows me my data when the IP I'm connecting from is one I have already used to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually google tends to be **user friendly** and it always wants to reduce our tension of often getting session_out problem. So it identifies our **static IP address** and stores the username and password of your google account in your cookies. So you don't want to often log in into it. **The best way is to use a separate mail for all your gaming purposes.**

Comment: Another incorrect answer. No sane system would store your username and password, but rather a session token cookie.

Comment: Yea, but when you apply the process of reverse engineering you can crack the username from the session token which has the details in an encrypted manner and even you can do it if you know.

Comment: Still, the password isn't stored in plaintext, as it wouldn't be useful alone to access the account (e.g. with 2FA).

Comment: Yeah but once if someone knows your email and password then he can break 2FA with SS7 attack and easily get access to your account. Right?

Comment: but password isn't stored in any form in the session cookie. That's why you can revoke a session from your account without changing the password.

Comment: Thanks, Manchineel for making me understand clear